# Have any new stylized facts of asset returns been discovered since 2001?

Tags: stylized-facts

In 2001 R.Cont stated in ["Empirical properties of asset returns: stylized facts
and statistical issues"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/713665670) article a set of stylized statistical facts which are common to a wide set of financial assets. The set was later reproduced  with minor changes in ["Encyclopedia of Quantitative Finance"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470061602) in 2010.

Here is the set:

1. Absence of autocorrelations
2. Heavy tails
3. Gain/Loss assymetry
4. Aggregational Gaussianity (later renamed to "Aggregational normality")
5. Intermittency (later excluded from the set)
6. Volatility clustering
7. Conditional heavy tails
8. Slow decay of autocorrelation in absolute returns
9. Leverage effect
10. Volume/volatility correlation
11. Assymetry in time scales

Have any new candidates into the stylized facts set been discovered since then?

Comment: Maybe some new features regarding intraday / high-frequency data? I am thinking about intraday seasonality for example.

Answer (score 4):

I think there has been established a strong argument for **jumps** (both in prices and volatility!). Jumps seem to matter a lot for explaining the distribution of volatility and price increments, as well as for option pricing. See *Broadie, Chernov and Johannes (2007)* [link](http://www.columbia.edu/~mnb2/broadie/Assets/BCJ_jf_2007.pdf) for further reference.